# Passing a data constructor instead of a Type constructor on a function

Tags: haskell

```
data GsdCommand =  CreateWorkspace { commandId :: CommandId , workspaceId ::WorkspaceId , workspaceName :: Text }
             | RenameWorkspace { commandId :: CommandId , workspaceId ::WorkspaceId , workspaceNewName :: Text }
             | SetGoal  { commandId :: CommandId ,
                          workspaceId ::WorkspaceId ,
                          goalId :: GoalId ,
                          goalDescription :: Text} deriving Show
```

I would like to handle a specific command into one function, 
 e.g in pseudo code :

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
handle :: 'CreateWorkspace -> CommandDirective GsdState
```

I was thinking that I could lift value constructors into types, but I don't know how to do it actually...

Comment: BTW, mixing different record constructors together typically isn't a very good idea.

Comment: To be clear, you want to define a function `handle :: GsdCommand -> CommandDirective GsdState` that *only* accepts a value created by `CreateWorkspace`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1: Don't get fancy, use Haskell 98 compatible types**

The first solution I recommend is using a separate record type.  This doesn't require any fancy type system hackery and avoids the partial functions implicit in your record field names.

```
type CommandId = ()
type WorkspaceId = ()
type Text = ()

data GsdCreate = GsdCreate { gsdcCommandId     :: CommandId
                           , gsdcWorkspaceId   :: WorkspaceId
                           , gsdcWorkspaceName :: Text
                           }
        deriving (Show)

data GsdCommand =  CreateWorkspace GsdCreate
             | RenameWorkspace { commandId :: CommandId
                               , workspaceId ::WorkspaceId
                               , workspaceNewName :: Text }
             | SetGoal  { commandId :: CommandId ,
                          workspaceId ::WorkspaceId ,
                          goalDescription :: Text }
        deriving (Show)

type CommandDirective a = Maybe a
type GsdState = ()

handle :: GsdCreate -> CommandDirective GsdState
handle = undefined
```

Aside:  I'm actually in favor of Haskell eliminating `data` as we know it and instead having:

- `Record` for single constructor types with field names
- `data` without field names but with multiple constructors.

**Solution 2: Use GADTs and DataKinds**

This solution is a bit overkill for your example, but perhaps your real problem has a need that isn't presented in the snippet.  The idea is to create a new data type that defines tags for your constructors and to use those constructors as types for a GADT:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

type CommandId = ()
type WorkspaceId = ()
type Text = ()

data Ty = Create | Rename | Set

data GsdCommand a where
  CreateWorkspace :: CommandId -> WorkspaceId -> Text -> GsdCommand Create
  RenameWorkspace :: CommandId -> WorkspaceId -> Text -> GsdCommand Rename
  SetGoal         :: CommandId -> WorkspaceId -> Text -> GsdCommand Set

type CommandDirective a = Maybe a
type GsdState = ()

handle :: GsdCommand Create -> CommandDirective GsdState
handle = undefined
```

Comment: Note you can also keep the record syntax with the GADT: `CreateWorkspace :: { commandId ::CommandID, ...} -> GsdCommand Create`, etc.

Comment: Explicit promotion to the type level, as with `'Create`, is not necessary.

Comment: Oh, right, because the compiler knows that `GsdCommand` has to take a type, not a function/data constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this approach is enough for what you want. Below is a variant of the `Either` type, but tagged with `L` (left) and `R` (right) annotations, and with projections `l` and `r`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module G where

data L
data R

data E d a b where
  L :: {l :: a} -> E L a b 
  R :: {r :: b} -> E R a b 

foo :: E L a b -> a
foo (L x) = x
```

Function `foo` and the projection `l` work only on left values, and `r` works only on right values.